# How to add missing methods to classes in a type hierarchy to allow for uniform processing?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I'm using Java 8 / Java 11. I have a type hierarchy (basically dtos or Java Beans) like

```
public abstract class Animal {
  public abstract String getName();
  public abstract int getAge();
}
```

And some imeplementations providing additional properties:

```
public class Dog extends Animal {

  // implementation of abstract methods from base class animal

  // additional properties
  public String getSound() {
    return "woof";
  }
}

public class Dog extends Animal {

  // implementation of abstract methods from base class animal

  // additional properties
  public String getSound() {
    return "miaow";
  }
}

public class Fish extends Animal {
  // implementation of abstract methods from base class animal

  // no implementaion for "getSound()"
}
```

Now, I'd like to process a `Collection` of `Animal`s in a uniform way, e.g.

```
animals.forEach(x -> {
  System.out.println(x.getName());  // works
  System.out.println(x.getSound();  // doesn't work, as Fish is missing the method
});
```

I was wondering, what would be a good way to implement the "missing" methods assuming that they should return a default value like "n/a" for a `String`.

One obvious way would be to move all the missing methods to the base class and either declare them abstract or provide a default implementation.
But I'd like to have them more separate, i.e. making clear which properties were added for the "uniform processing".
Another way would be to introduce a helper class using `instance of` to determine, if the method is missing:

```
public class AnimalHelper {

  public static String getSoundOrDefault(Animal animal) {
    if (animal instanceof Dog) {
        return ((Dog)animal).getSound();
    }

    if (animal instanceof Cat) {
        return ((Cat)animal).getSound();
    }
    return "n/a";
  }
}
```

which then gets called with an `Animal`:

```
System.out.println(AnimalHelper.getSoundOrDefault(animal));
```

This works, but the caller must now which methods to call on `Animal` directly and for which methods to use the helper.

Another solution, I came up with the adding an interface `AnimalAdapter` using the Java 8 feature of default implementation:

```
public interface AnimalAdapter {

  default String getSoundOrDefault() {
    return "n/a";
  }
}
```

And adding it to the `Animal` class:

```
public abstract class Animal implements AnimalAdapter {
...
```

which results in adding the `getSoundOrDefault()` method in `Dog` and `Cat`, but not `Fish`:

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
  ...
  @Override
  public String getSoundOrDefault() {
    return getSound();
  }
}
```

(likewise in `Cat`).

Any comments on the above considerations or other ideas would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

All what you have mentioned above as solutions are really good. But I take advantage to add more one solution based on polymorphism technic, and I think it's more simple and less expensive in terms of code.
Simply I'm gonna use **Object.toString()** method to display all needed parameters, so first of all you have to @Override toString() method as follow:

```js
  public class Dog extends Animal {

      // implementation of abstract methods from base class animal

      // additional properties
      public String getSound() {
        return "woof";
      }

       @Override
       public String toString() {
        return getName() + "\n" + getSound();
       }
  }

  public class Fish extends Animal {

      // implementation of abstract methods from base class animal

      // no implementaion for "getSound()"

      @Override
      public String toString() {
        return getName() + "\n" + "n/a";
      }
  }

  public class Main {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
       Collection<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>(2);
       animals.add(new Dog());
       animals.add(new Fish());
       animals.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
 }
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but printing the fields with `System.out.println` is just an example for calling methods on the classes. Sorry, if I didn't make that clear in my post. How could I use your solution if I wanted to "call" the `getSounds()` (or a similar method) on each `Animal` object in a `Collection` and process the results (and not just print them)?